# App crashing immediately on start up, on device only

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I'm trying to figure out why an app I'm developing has started crashing immediately when running it on my device (an iPhone 4 running iOS 6.1). I have been working on this app for about 8 weeks and this problem has arisen seemingly out of the blue.

The app runs fine when I run it on the simulator. When I try to run it on my device it crashes, and breaks at:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

The crash happens before the AppDelegate method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

gets called.

I have looked at the device crash log, and I don't see anything that gave me a clue as to what is happening. Does anyone have an idea of where I can start looking for a solution? For what it's worth, here is the crash log:

> Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000 Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread Thread 0
>   Crashed: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib           0x39e74350 __pthread_kill
>   + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x39deb11e pthread_kill + 54 2   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39e2796e abort + 90 3
>   GraphicsServices                  0x357da9ce GSRegisterPurpleNamedPort +
>   210 4   GraphicsServices                  0x357da684 _GSEventInitialize +
>   92 5   UIKit                          0x33b2d0c8 UIApplicationMain +
>   552 6   CK-Ranker                         0x000bbaf4 main (main.m:16) 7
>   CK-Ranker                         0x000bba7c start + 36
>
> Thread 1: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e74d98
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39dc2cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x39dc2a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x39dc28a0 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager Thread
>   2: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x39e64648 kevent64 + 24 1
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x39d9d4ec _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 792 2
>   libdispatch.dylib                 0x39d8fdf4
>   _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$up + 32
>
> Thread 3: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e74d98
>   __workq_kernreturn + 8 1   libsystem_c.dylib              0x39dc2cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14 2   libsystem_c.dylib                 0x39dc2a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362 3   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x39dc28a0 start_wqthread + 4
>
> Thread 4 name:  WebThread Thread 4: 0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x39e63eb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 1   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>     0x39e64048 mach_msg + 36 2   CoreFoundation
>     0x31ca6040 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 124 3   CoreFoundation
>     0x31ca4d9e __CFRunLoopRun + 878 4   CoreFoundation
>     0x31c17eb8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 352 5   CoreFoundation
>     0x31c17d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100 6   WebCore
>     0x37c16500 RunWebThread(void*) + 440 7   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x39dcd30e _pthread_start + 306 8   libsystem_c.dylib
>     0x39dcd1d4 thread_start + 4
>
> Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
>       r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x3b92d534
>       r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3b92db88      r6: 0x3b933ff4      r7: 0x2fd46c48
>       r8: 0x1ed7a570    r9: 0x001844f0     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x00000000
>       ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x2fd46c3c      lr: 0x39deb123      pc: 0x39e74350   cpsr: 0x00000010

I am running Xcode 4.6.1 with ARC enabled.

Comment: Have to tried deleting the app from the device?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention, I have tried deleting the app from the device, doing a clean, restarting Xcode, and rebooting my computer.

Comment: did you modify the `main` method? do you have any code that may run during initialization? e.g. `+load`, c++ constructor

Comment: My main method is just what I posted. I don't have any other special code that runs during initialization that I know of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out there was a problem with my device. I reset my device and the crash disappeared. In future I'll be sure to remember to try resetting my device when I run into this crash.

Answer (score 4):

You need to give some more code or tell what does your app do on startup.

But its clear from the crash logs that the `Thread0` that main UI thread has been killed. This could be because on device there is a process called `watchdog`, it kills any processes which seem dubious. like take too much memory or take take too much time to show first screen on app startup & other things which "Apple" thinks would affect user experience. So...

Comment: The watchdog timer seems very likely here since the timeout is much longer on the simulator than the device...

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with the watchdog, but my app is getting killed before the didFinishLoading method is called. What code could I post? What is my app actually doing before getting to this point? I can't find any part of my code that is getting called. Also, I'm not seeing the 0x8BADF00D error code. Also, the app crashes very quickly, within a few seconds.

Comment: If your code is breaking at `main` at startup it looks like it is not even started to execute your code. something went wrong before that. I want to know what are you doing at app startup. esp. the `ViewController` you would have implemented which plugs into your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: The app is crashing before any of my view controllers code is called. At startup the storyboard points to a PKRevealController (https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController) a class that mimics the "Facebook" style home page. None of my content view controllers are initialized prior to the app crashing, and none of the PKRevealController code methods are called prior to the app crashing.

Comment: I as earlier hypothesized the crash is happening before your code is getting executed. Your thread `pthread_kill` is killed. Are you making any lengthy HTTP calls on startup? or is there some uninitialized code ? or some dynamic libraries not properly linked? basically I am trying to ascertain reasons for your app getting killed...

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped me narrow down the possibilities. As it turns out, one thing I hadn't tried was resetting my device. That fixed my problem. If you add my solution to the end of your answer, I'll mark it as correct, as I used your help to work towards a solution, and your answer could help someone in the future.

Comment: It's not the watchdog since it gets disabled in debug builds connected to xcode's debugger

Comment: @Dario: nice comment. I had forgotten the watchdog is disabled when connected to Xcode debugger to allow for the extra time penalties that Xcode incurs to do its stuff. That will probably help me in the future, as I had really though that was the problem.